# Docker Error: Invalid Reference Format

Tags: docker, clojure

When trying to do a `docker load`, I am getting the `invalid reference type` error. I do `docker load -i name-of-tar-file`.
That's the only error I see, with no additional information.

Some additional context: This is a project in Clojure. I recently updated some code (it was literally a 1 line change, pretty minor too). The previous 'version' of my code works just fine, this updated one doesn't. 
I haven't been able to find answers on SO about seeing this error when doing `docker load`

Edit:
Some more context: I have an arraymap called `result`. Earlier, I was replacing `:images` with the placeholder, but I now I want it replaced only if `:images` and `:og-images` is empty.
Here's the original code:

```
(cond-> result
          ;; If no images, use placeholder.
          (empty? (:images result)) (image-util/assoc-placeholder))
```

This is what I changed it to:

```
(cond-> result
          ;; If no images at all, use placeholder.
          (and (empty? (:images result)) (empty? (:og-images result))) (image-util/assoc-placeholder))
```

And in a separate file, the version number had to be updated.

Comment: Could you post the line you changed in its old and new form? Ideally, with a little bit of context around.

Comment: I was able to figure this thing out. In the file where my version was changed, a newline was being added by Atom. Since another file slurps the version number from here, it caused it to break.
Conclusion: Invalid Reference Type ALWAYS implies some character causing trouble

Answer (score 1):

a couple common debugging steps:

- can the docker image built from the updated Clojure code be run on the same same where it was built? before the docker save/load?
- can the result of docker save be passed to docker load on the same system?
- if you run sha256hash or md5sum does it match on both the system where docker save was run and where docker load was run?
- are there file sizes reasonable?

Comment: The answer is yes for points 1,4. Im not doing `docker save`. CircleCI builds it for me